# Datebox execute an alert if highDate - Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I have a calbox with an array of highDates in options:

```
<input name="date" id="date" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "hideInput": true, "useSetButton":false, "useInline": true, "useImmediate":true, "calHighToday":false, "calHighPick":false, "highDates":["2012-06-20", "2012-06-21"], "themeDateHigh":"b" }'>
```

And I want to when I click on one of these highDates execute an alert. Only if it is a highDate.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind to the `set` payload event as described in the [DateBox Events documentation](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/api/events.html).

```
$('document').bind('pagecreate', function() {
  $('element').bind('datebox', function(e, p) {
    if ( p.method === 'set' ) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();

      var myHighDates = $('#date').data('datebox').options.highDates;
      var dateClicked = p.value;

      //DateBox seems to be using diff formats :(
      //Need to convert dateClicked into format matching HighDate 

      if(myHighDates.indexOf(dateClicked) != -1) {
         console.log('highDate clicked:'+dateClicked);
      }else {
         console.log('another date clicked:'+dateClicked );            
      }

    }
  });
});
```

Here's [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Y9h9/10/) with the code I tried... the problem I ran into was that the date formats aren't matching... you will have to put in some code to make them similar for `indexOf` to work.

Comment: My idea was to see if the color of the button highlighted date is different from the color of the other buttons of the dates .. Only that I am not able to do that.